# PhpStorm nested git repos

Tags: git, version-control, phpstorm

I have a PhpStorm project which is a git repo at its root directory.
It also has nested git repos.
I have edited the .gitmodules file as below.

I used to be able to right click the root directory, do GIT Add, GIT commit and git Push and the main and nested repos would all be respectively pushed to remote.

And obviously vice versa on another machine I would be able to right click and GIT PULL the root project and changes to nested repos.

The problem is currently that I have to push each nested repo separately to main one and then the opposite to pull them on another machine.

```
    [submodule "app/DD_laravelAp"]
    path = app/DD_laravelAp
    url = https://github.com/datadimension/DD_laravelAp.git
[submodule "public/DD_libmedia"]
    path = public/DD_libmedia
    url = https://github.com/datadimension/DD_libmedia.git
[submodule "public/DD_libwww"]
    path = public/DD_libwww
    url = https://github.com/datadimension/DD_libwww.git
[submodule "resources/views/DD_laraview"]
    path = resources/views/DD_laraview
    url = https://github.com/datadimension/DD_laraview.git
```

Answer (score 0):

PhpStorm doesn't support pushing to all/multiple branches currently. The feature is still WIP:

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-200338
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-136317
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128645
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-188212

Answer (score 0):

What I want appears to be a subtle feature:

[image]

So where I usually right click a directory, I click it to focus on the project files and then CTRL A which selects the entire project. Right clicking on the whole highlighted project gives option to 'Commit Directories' [plural]. And again also option to 'Push Commits'.

[image]